# Vue Js Authentication with keeping same url for home component and login component

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, vue.js, identityserver4, server-side-rendering

How can I implement authentication with keeping URL same in browser as facebook does?

If user is authenticated, it shows home page, if not, it shows login page. But in both case URL is same.

How can I achieve that using Vue js.

I don't want to keep home page html at client side if not authenticated (might be server side rendering will require for this scenario).

I have used asp.net core, identity server 4, typescript, webpack in project.

Comment: The section that renders your frontpage, wether its backend or frontend rendering, can check wether the user is authenticated and then simply return a different page - you don't have to redirect. Now if you use client side rendering it'll obviously be accessible anyway with some manipulation of the running javascript, but that's just the deal with client-side rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following thread might help. It has different solutions.

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/76

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like,

```
<div v-if="isAuthenticated">
   <!-- Main Page -->
<div>
<div v-else>
   <!-- Login Page -->
<div>
```

isAuthenticated is a function which checks if user is authenticated or not.

Comment: This is what I have done currently. But that will have both components to load (even if one is not visible at DOM) as it is client side decision. I don't want to load other component unnecessarily.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you don't want to load both components on client side. Using Backend rendering just for the sack of authentication seems like overkill.

Comment: I don't want to render other unused heavily loaded component unnecessarily. :)

Comment: The component would just be loaded. It won't render.